# XML и кодировка

Tags: xml, кодировка, php

В общем, имеется база данных в кодировке latin1.
Имеется .php файл, кодировка файла UTF8.
В .php файле генерируется xml код, ну и выводится. 
Как можно совладать с кодировками?

Comment: `iconv` - попробовать переводить из одной кодировки в другую, скорее всего ваш `latin1` в `utf8`.

Comment: UTF наше все. Даешь возможность кодировать базу? да. Или мучатся с mb_string

Comment: Пришлось конвертить базу, довольно просто напросто, довольно сложно было объяснить заказчику зачем...

Answer (score 1):

Многие этого не знают, но mysql может перекодировать данные на лету. Именно для этой цели служит волшебное заклинание `SET NAMES`.

То есть, чтобы получить utf-8 из latin1, надо всего лишь выполнить запрос

```
SET NAMES utf8
```

а потом спокойно запросить свои данные и записать их в XML.

А кодировка самого РНР файла в данном случае абсолютно перпендикулярна.